# Is it possible to get server name from nativePath in Flex Air?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flex4, filesystems

I have a nativePath of a file somewhere hosted in server and the value of this nativePath as flex shows me as

Z:\myFolder\myFile.ext

which, **I know** is also equivalent to

http://particularDomain.myCompany.com/myFolder/myFile.ext

(Note - Z: maps to http://particularDomain.myCompany.com/ which is true in my system and my colleague can have it mapped the same sever to A: in his system)

Now my question is - Can this mapping be realized through Air application in any way? i.e if the native file lies in http://particularDomain.myCompany.com/myFolder/myFile.ext, it says that it lies in that particular server irrespective of whatever it is mapped to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this mapping cannot be realized through any functionality provided in AIR.

How would your AIR app know that there is a web server whose root directory is 'Z:\'?  It can't unless you tell it to.

Now, it may be possible to create this functionality on your own as long as you give it a few specific parameters.

If you're app knows that particluarDomain.myCompany.com points to Z:\ it should be easy to write some code to map the two.  You could even encapsulate out the domain name and the root in order to easily change them in the future.

You may, also, in theory parse the config file of an Apache Web Server in order to determine the server root and directory location.  Assuming that your local machine has access to both.  If you're mapping network locations to a local drive; this could potentially complicate things, though.

Comment: I knew it was too vague to think that an air app can have that functionality. I think the best way to deal with this would be give the user a freedom to map the drive letter to network themselves to get the appropriate network path.